# whilw performing CURD operation i got error. Using the URLconf defined in Student.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django

Using the URLconf defined in Student.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
emp [name='emp']
show [name='show']
edit/int:roll_no [name='edit']
update/int:roll_no [name='update']
delete/int:roll_no [name='delete']
The current path, update/, didn’t match any of these.
While Performing django CURD operation I got above error..

my code from main( student urls.py):-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('stud_details.urls'))
```

from app stud_details(urls.py)

```
from stud_details import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index),
    path("emp",views.emp, name='emp'),
    path("show",views.show, name='show'),
    path("edit/<int:roll_no>",views.edit, name='edit'),
    path("update/<int:roll_no>",views.update, name='update'),
    path("delete/<int:roll_no>",views.destroy, name='delete')
```

from views.py:

```
from stud_details.forms import Stud_form
from stud_details.models import Stud_class    

 def emp(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = Stud_form(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = Stud_class()  
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})    

def show(request):  
    students = Stud_class.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"show.html",{'students':students})        

def index(request):  
    return render(request,"index.html")      

def edit(request, roll_no):  
    students = Stud_class.objects.get(roll_no=roll_no)  
    return render(request,'edit.html', {'students':students})  

def update(request, roll_no):  
    students = Stud_class.objects.get(roll_no=roll_no)
    form = Stud_form(request.POST, instance = students)
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect("/show")  
        return render(request, 'edit.html', {'Stud_class': employee})  

def destroy(request, roll_no):  
    students = Stud_class.objects.get(roll_no=roll_no)  
    students.delete()  
    return redirect("/show")
```

What I'm doing wrong

Comment: You are trying to access the URL `update/`, for which you have not defined any route. The code you have included doesn't show us where you are doing that - possibly in your template.

Comment: thank you for commenting, can you please give me solution for this